# How to logout from Bluemix Single Sign On service?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am using Single Sign On Cloud Directory service in Bluemix from Node.js

After reading the [docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index.html) and browsing some files like authenticator.js from the downloaded necessary module I haven't found any API documentation or function to logout.

Is it available such function? Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible based on [link](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/164923/logout-from-sso-service-on-bluemix.html) this thread. I am not sure something changed since that was posted.

Comment: Instead of relying on SSO or a browser cookie to maintain the state of the login, create a session database table mapping the session ID stored in an encrypted browser cookie into a private session ID used by the application (table includes the last access time to enable session expiration). To handle logout, simply remove the row mapping the session known to the browser into one known to the application. If the user accesses the application again, no match is found and they're directed to the login page. I wrote a sample to demonstrate this approach, but it uses the (now deprecated) V1 API.

Comment: @chemi is your issue resolved?

Comment: @JeffSloyer I didn't found how to do it with SSO service API which was my question. I can't confirm there is no way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node.js you can just simply destroy the session.  The call to `request.logout()` will destroy the session.

```
app.get("/logout", function (request, response) {
    request.logout();
    response.redirect("/");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and come back to you.

Comment: I tried the suggestion but it doesn't work. It seems the browser maintains the token, so next browsing page still sending the info and the server shows the logged user. Should I execute any token invalidation or anything similar aditionally?

Comment: `request.logout()` should destroy the token.

Comment: It doesn't, I can still browsing the app with no login challenge appearing and at server side I still have access to the logged user.

Comment: You are browsing to /logout and then you still have access to the users info? Try dumping request.cookies and request.headers server side.